# Eclipse JUNO won't start anymore - org.eclipse.equinox.launcher

Tags: eclipse, windowbuilder

I have today installed the software "WindowBuilder" with the "Help -> Install Software Function" and rebooted the eclipse client (v4.2) aftwerwards, i work with the IBM Rational Application Developer. Now it won't start anymore and tell me to check the report log. The report log tells me following:

```
!SESSION Thu May 16 11:37:41 CEST 2013 -----------------------------------------
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.launcher 4 0 2013-05-16 11:37:41.048
!MESSAGE Exception launching the Eclipse Platform:
!STACK
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Unknown Source)
```

Did anyone else expierience something like this yet or is someone able to analyze what is wrong? I would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the clean option :

- Edit the `eclipse.ini` file located in your Eclipse install directory and insert -clean as the first line.
- Or edit the shortcut you use to start Eclipse and add `-clean` as the first argument.